# Laravel laravelcollective/html textarea with unescaped html

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I have a form made with the laravelcollective/html form package. Now I'd like to enter unescaped HTML Markup in a textarea:

```
<p>This is HTML-Markup text</p>
```

My form looks like this:

```
{!! Form::label('body', 'Body:') !!}
{!! Form::textarea('body' , null , ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

I tried it with `{{ }}` but it still escapes the HTML in the textarea.

Also: Is there a way to limit the allowed HTML-Markups (probably with a **regex**) ? E.g. only `<p>, <h1> and <div>` and no `<script>`.

I'm using Laravel 5.2.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `{{!!    !!}}`  for show result textarea

> By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
{!! $str!!}
```

Comment: print_r result in controller. mybe in null.

Comment: I don't see how this would help